# According to Catholic beliefs, why did God appear to Elijah as a whisper?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, elijah

In the Bible it says:

"As the Lord approached, a very powerful wind tore the mountains apart. It broke up the rocks. But the Lord wasn’t in the wind. After the wind, there was an earthquake. But the Lord wasn’t in the earthquake. 12 After the earthquake, a fire came. But the Lord wasn’t in the fire. And after the fire, there was only a gentle whisper. 13 When Elijah heard it, he pulled his coat over his face. He went out and stood at the entrance to the cave.

Then a voice said to him, “Elijah, what are you doing here?”

So why did God appear in the whisper to Elijah? What would be the theological interpretation?

Comment: This is only a comment, not an  answer, because I'm not sure there's any official teaching about this, but here's my opinion: This could be one aspect of God's preparing Israel to receive Christ. Instead of expecting a powerful political or military leader, they should prepare to receive a gentle (even sacrificial) Lamb. As a first step in this direction, God makes it clear that He is not always to be found in power but also in gentleness.

Comment: I believe that the title should bare the term manifest in lieu of appear. I do not see how God appeared to Elijah, but rather God manifested Himself to Elijah  as a gentle whisper.